# OpenIAB Xcode Build Error

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm using Simple IAP and OpenIAB system.

I have no problem Android system but i tried Xcode for IOS I have an error.

I added StoreKit framework.

```
"_Inventory_removePurchase", referenced from:

    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o

"_Inventory_query", referenced from:

    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o

"_AppStore_requestProducts", referenced from:

    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o

"_Inventory_hasPurchase", referenced from:

    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o

"_AppStore_startPurchase", referenced from:

    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o

"_AppStore_restorePurchases", referenced from:

    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Uik.png

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: have you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have added the following files to your project:

**AppStoreBridge.mm, AppStoreDelegate.h, 
AppStoreDelegate.mm**

Without these files present, you will encounter the above framework errors when trying to build.